# Go to the file and line in Visual Studio Code tooltips

Tags: visual-studio-code, tooltip

Tooltips sometimes are very useful in VS code a specially when they hint what is the class or where variable is defined.

Is it possible somehow by clicking on hint to go to the line and file to which hint is applying to?

I tried with ctrl+click, shift+click and others... None of them works.[image]